# Jquery: Selecting only first occurences of class in tree

Tags: jquery

I have a structure as follows:

```
<div class="root-configuration" data-fullkey="abc.def.123">
    <label></label>
    <div id="sublevel1">
        <div id="sublevel2 (or 3 or 4...)">
            <div class="one-configuration-key"> <!-- YES -->
                ...
                <div class="one-configuration-key"></div> <!-- NO -->
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="one-configuration-key"> <!-- YES -->
        <somehtmlelements....>
            <div class="one-configuration-key"></div> <!-- NO -->
        </somehtmlelements....>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need to is select all elements with class "one-configuration-key" under "root-configuration". The thing is, that there can be HTML Elements between the "root-configuration" and "one-configuration-key", so `.children(".one-configuration-key")` won't work here.

But when I use `$(".root-configuration").find(".one-configuration-key")` I get all elements, because there are sub-sub-sub-childs in the tree. But I only want to select the first occurence in the tree.

I marked the DIV-Elements with "YES" which I'd like to select.
The "NO" DIV-Elements should not be selected.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: `$(".root-configuration").find(".one-configuration-key").not('.one-configuration-key .one-configuration-key')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to get is all the `.one-configuration-key` that are not children of another `.one-configuration-key`. so you can select all the `.one-configuration-key` and then filter them by not being a child of another `.one-configuration-key`:

```
$('.root-configuration .one-configuration-key').not('.one-configuration-key .one-configuration-key')
```

Comment: Have you an idea, how to make the same with an level deeper? So the start is e.g. the first "YES" "one-configuration-key" and the result should be the next "one-configuration-key" (so in this case, the first "NO"?)

Comment: For thath, you can add another ` .one-configuration-key` to `.not()` method; but I'm not sure if it's a good approach or not.

Comment: Hm okay...but that would only work for 2-Deepness, right? Not n-deepness ;)

Comment: I wrote a function for you; check it out to see if it answers your question: https://jsfiddle.net/faridv/mn9atq64/8/

Comment: Thanks but the problem is, that the deepness is unknown. I just need to get the next class element (and only the next, not the next and all under the next) from an element on.

Comment: So you want all the children except the last one. is that right?

Comment: No only the children, and no children from the children. Solved it by using level generation in the backend and combined with your answer. So it's solved, thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".root-configuration").find(".one-configuration-key").first()
```

or

```
$(".root-configuration").children(".one-configuration-key")[0];
```

they must work.

Comment: your code just selects the first `.one-configuration-key`, not all the elements that the OP wants to select.

Comment: @FaridRn he want:"But I only want to select the first occurence in the tree."

Comment: he wants the first occurance on each node of tree, not just the first occurance of the `.one-configuration-key`.